К вечеру это обстоятелтьство или дополнение?
К вечеру это обстоятельство или дополнение?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Когда? - к вечеру - обстоятельство: к вечеру все разошлись по домам ~ вечером все разошлись. К чему? - дополнение: она выбирала платье к вечеру ~ она выбирала платье для вечера/ а не "вечером".
